# angularJs: unable to see data from form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I've a simple form. I accept a (required) text.

When submitted, just to check this step, I want to print to js console the submitted data. But I can't.

**html**

```
<form action="" name="search_form" 
      novalidate 
      ng-controller="SearchController as src"
      ng-submit="search_form.$valid && src.searchCode()">

     <div bs-panel title="Giacenza per prodotto">

        <input
            bs-form-control
            required
            type="text"
            ng-model="src.product.code"
            label="Prodotto"
            label-class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1"
            class="col-xs-9 col-sm-10 col-lg-11"
            placeholder="Cod. Phonix"
        />

     </div>

    <div bs-panel class="form-actions">
        <div content-for="navbarAction" duplicate>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                Cerca  
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

** js **

```
app.controller('SearchController', function($scope) {

   $scope.product = {
        code : "",
   }

   this.searchCode = function () {
        console.warn ($scope.product.code);
   };

});
```

**Problem** Console writes 'empty string' even if I've inserted some data into the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    <input
        bs-form-control
        required
        type="text"
        ng-model="product.code"
        label="Prodotto"
        label-class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1"
        class="col-xs-9 col-sm-10 col-lg-11"
        placeholder="Cod. Phonix"
    />
```

You have to remove the `src` from the ng-model in your input field.

Comment: Yes, it works, but can you exaplain why ? I found a very similar example on the course of codeschool. It told to add controller alias to every single ng-model of the form. (And it worked)

Comment: You are inside the scope of your controller. So, angularjs already "knows" in which scope you are. Therefore you don't have to use `src` as a reference to your controller, because you are already in its scope.